# SumIf with string comparison criteria

Tags: excel-formula

The problem I am trying to solve involves comparing range values that are strings as if they where numbers.

For example the range values are "1d" "2d" "3d" ... "20d"
The criteria is less than or equal to 3d
The issue is that values in the columns after "10d" are included.

This is because 
"9d"<="3d" is false.
"10d"<="3d" is true.

What the users want is that they act like numbers.
I can't remove the "d" from the cells.
Is there a way to strip the "d" from the range values in this formula?

Comment: can you add a 0 so that 01d 02d exists? then do the compare?  OR (assuming "D" is only one character in all cases... `=int(left(string,len(string)-1))`

Comment: I can't change the range values at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see it you have three options:

1. Construct an array formula: I have been unsuccessful in trying to find one that works in this case.  Maybe someone else can help
2. Add an intermediate column with a formula to sanitise your data (this leaves the original data intact).  What formula depends on the exact nature of your `d`'s.  If they are always a single `d`, `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"d",""))` would work.  Then apply your formula to this column
3. Write a UDF to do the lot in one formula

Comment: 2. This is a good answer. However the users don't want extra values in the worksheet.

Comment: 3. Best answer. The only issues left are business ones, who will maintain and extend this now? Why are critical business processes driven by an Excel sheet someone is emailing around the company? Where is the budget to fix this properly? The usual.

Answer (score 0):

If the values always include just "d" you could use =HEX2DEC() to convert it as a hexidecimal and evaluate it that way.

Comment: How would I apply the HEX2DEC to the range values?

Comment: In a formula you would just use =HEX2DEC(A1) or whatever your range is.

Comment: A bit like this? =sumif(HEX2DEC(A1:F1);2;A2:F2) However it does not seem you can do the Hex2Dec on the range as I need too.